# Bootstrap, how to prevent from closing a dropdown-menu when modal popup displayed

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

Inside a dropdown-menu I have a button to open a modal popup. If you display the modal popup when you close it, it will also close the dropdown-menu.

How to prevent from closing a dropdown-menu when a modal popup is displayed ?

This is the code :

```
 <div class="dropdown-menu" style="width:240px;">

   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6">Log in</div>
      <div class="col-xs-6"><img data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" width="20px" src="images/help-question.png"></div>
  </div>
...
</div>
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">

  <!-- Modal content-->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">

   etc...

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, I have found a solution :)

```
  var hideLogin = true ;
  $('#ModalHelpLogin').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
    hideLogin = false ;
  })
  $('#ModalHelpLogin').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
    hideLogin = true ;
  })

  $('#DropLogin').on('hide.bs.dropdown', function () {
    return hideLogin ;
  });
```

Comment: hi, do you have a vanilla js version of this? i'm having the same problem but my boss wants a non-jquery solution.. I don't know the event handler for on show/hide in vanilla js